# Docker - managing size of containers

Tags: docker, rhel, device-mapper

I need more than 10G of disc space in my container to run application. But 10G is set as a default maximum size of containers. I am running RHEL 7, so devicemapper as well. I've found this:

`docker -d --storage-opt dm.basesize=25G`

Before that, what I did was: `rm -rf /var/lib/docker` to delete all docker images, and `systemctl stop docker.service`.

What i get is:

`INFO[0000] +job serveapi(unix:///var/run/docker.sock)`

`INFO[0000] Listening for HTTP on unix (/var/run/docker.sock)`

`INFO[0004] +job init_networkdriver()`

`INFO[0004] -job init_networkdriver() = OK (0)`

`INFO[0004] Loading containers: start.`

`INFO[0004] Loading containers: done.`

`INFO[0004] docker daemon: 1.5.0-dev fc0329b/1.5.0; execdriver: native-0.2; graphdriver: devicemapper`

`INFO[0004] +job acceptconnections()`

`INFO[0004] -job acceptconnections() = OK (0)`

After that nothing is happening. Has someone seen something familiar?

Comment: What do you mean by 'nothing is happening'? What is supposed to happen if you've removed everything and then started docker as a background process on empty database?

Comment: Your question might be better suited for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/)